# Filter data based on dropdown values in webpage for SQL Server stored procedure

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I want to filter data for `Items` based on `ProductCategory`, `ProductSubCategory` and `YEAR`. I have three drop-downs with `ProductCategory`, `ProductSubCategory` and `YEAR` and based on user selection I want to show the data.

User can filter data based on any drop-down selection and id user doesn't selection anything then it should show all records by default.

I need to write a stored procedure with 3 parameters for same to work properly, I had been advised to use following query

```
SELECT *    
FROM Products
WHERE (CatID = 0 OR CatID IS NULL)
  AND (CatSubID = 0 OR CatSubID IS NULL)
  AND (DATEPART(YY, PubDate) = 0 OR DATEPART(YY, PubDate) IS NULL)
```

Issue with this query is I don't have `Null` values, I have 0 in the database if it is not assigned to any category or sub category and year part is never NULL or has `0` and even if I change `0` to null it still doesn't fetch anything if don't select any value to dropdowns

`0` in `CatID` & `CatSubID` columns mean it has not been assigned to any category, so we can say `0` is a generic category for those products

Table `Products` data:

```
ID  Title       PubDate         Visible     CatID   CatSubID
------------------------------------------------------------
1   Title 1     2016-11-07      1           7       5
2   Title 2     2012-12-31      1           0       0
3   Title 3     2016-12-19      0           5       0
4   Title 4     2014-11-07      1           7       5
5   Title 5     2015-12-19      1           7       5
6   Title 6     2016-12-19      0           7       5
```

Example 1: CatID = 7, CatSubID = 5, Year = 2016

Results:

```
ID  Title       PubDate         Visible     CatID   CatSubID
------------------------------------------------------------
1   Title 1     2016-11-07      1           7       5
6   Title 6     2016-12-19      0           7       5
```

Example 2: CatID = 7, CatSubID = 0, Year = 0

Results:

```
ID  Title       PubDate         Visible     CatID   CatSubID
------------------------------------------------------------
1   Title 1     2016-11-07      1           7       5
4   Title 4     2014-11-07      1           7       5
5   Title 5     2015-12-19      1           7       5
6   Title 6     2016-12-19      0           7       5
```

Example 3: CatID = 0, CatSubID = 5, Year = 0

Results:

```
1   Title 1     2016-11-07      1           7       5
4   Title 4     2014-11-07      1           7       5
5   Title 5     2015-12-19      1           7       5
6   Title 6     2016-12-19      0           7       5
```

Example 4: CatID = 0, CatSubID = 0, Year = 0

Results: in this case it should show all records of the table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope this will work,

```
DECLARE @CatID    INT=0, 
        @CatSubID INT=0, 
        @YEAR     INT=0 

SELECT * 
FROM   #your_table 
WHERE  ( catid = CASE 
                   WHEN @CatID = 0 THEN catid 
                   ELSE @CatID 
                 END ) 
       AND ( catsubid = CASE 
                          WHEN @CatSubID = 0 THEN catsubid 
                          ELSE @CatSubID 
                        END ) 
       AND ( Year(pubdate) = CASE 
                               WHEN @YEAR = 0 THEN Year(pubdate) 
                               ELSE @YEAR 
                             END )
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you want this - if one of the params is zero, you skip the 2nd half of the OR clause for that param - you ignore it, in other words.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE procProducts
@catid INT,
@catsubid INT,
@year INT
AS
BEGIN

SELECT  *    
FROM Products
WHERE (@CatID = 0 OR @CatID = CatID)
AND (@CatSubID = 0 OR @CatSubID = CatSubID)
AND (@year = 0 OR @year = DATEPART(YY,PubDate))

END
GO

exec procProducts 0, 0, 0
```

Comment: I had tried this before this doen't get correct data

Comment: You sure? I'm pretty sure it works... The output matches for all your sample cases, anyway.

Comment: Yes, My mistake, It seems to be working, let me check all conditions

Comment: JUST WANT TO MENTION Your Query works as query but when i put this is stored procedure it doesn't work if i pass 0 value to year. While Solution given by `@PP006` works fine not sure why your query doesnt work

Comment: @Learning it absolutely works in a stored procedure. See the edit - I wrapped my original answer in a CREATE PROCEDURE statement. Works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

Considering your above query you can use simple solution:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[MyTable](
    [ID] [int] NULL,
    [Title] [nvarchar](250) NULL,
    [PubDate] [datetime] NULL,
    [Visible] [bit] NULL,
    [CatID] [int] NULL,
    [CatSubID] [int] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
```

If above table structure is correct then why not use below simplified query?

```
    create procedure Filter
        @CatID int
        ,@CatSubID int
        ,@Year int
    as
    begin
        select * from MyTable
        where CatID=@CatID and CatSubID=@CatSubID and year(PubDate)=@Year
    end
```

Comment: `PubDate` really should be a `DATE` or `DATETIME2(n)` column - don't just store everything as stirng out of lazyness ...... also: a parameter like `Year` will *most likely* be more of a **numerical** value - so you should use `INT` - again: don't just make everything a `varchar` because that saves you from thinking about your datatypes.... you should ***always*** use the **most appropriate** datatypes!

Comment: Check now! Thanks for the knowledge :)

Comment: But if your `CatId` and `CatSubId` **columns** in the table are `INT`, then your **parameters** to the `Filter` stored procedure also should be `INT`

Comment: Thanks again la. I really appreciate you for guiding me :)